# maven не включать jar библиотеки в формируемый war файл

Tags: java, maven, развертывание, war

Использую Eclipse, у меня есть проект `maven`, в котором есть некоторые зависимости. Сейчас мне требуется подготовить один из вариантов проекта, в который, помимо прочих изменений, при создании `war` файла не включать в него библиотеки.

Это если вкратце, ниже более подробно:

На данный момент в проекте есть `enum`, в котором перечислены вид сборки (`DEBUG_MODE`, `PRODUCTION_MODE`, `SINGLE_VERSION`)
Для `DEBUG_MODE` и `PRODUCTION_MODE` собираемый `.war` файл должен содержать в себе все подключённые библиотеки (они деплоятся на рабочий сервер).

`SINGLE_VERSION` же разворачивается на локальной машине. Связь может быть плохой, поэтому размер загружаемых файлов критичен. Как вариант: загрузить все используемые в проекте библиотеке на локальную машину и указать в `pom.xml`, чтобы их он искал в локальной директории.

Возможно ли, в зависимости от параметра сборки, указывать `maven'у` где искать используемые библиотеки, и, если да, то где взять информацию?

Я находил информацию, в которой объяснялось, как не включать библиотеки в выходной архив `war`. Также я находил информацию, в которой говорится, как указывать локальную директорию в качестве источника, в которой `maven` будет искать библиотеки. Но как сделать так, чтобы по изменению одного параметра он включался / не включался в выходной `war`, сделать этот момент опциональным? Также как можно указывать проекту, где искать эту библиотеку: в локальной директории, или же она лежит в самом архиве?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Если в архиве `war` библиотеки нет, тогда берётся общая библиотека c сервера приложений, например из папки `tomcat/lib`.</sub>

---

В настрокйах зависимойсей `maven` можно указать `scope` для каждой зависимости - включать ее в выходной архив `war` или нет:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>awesomeapp</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Либо можно общую настройку задать для всех зависимостей:

```xml
<properties>
    <dependency.scope>provided</dependency.scope>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>awesomeapp</artifactId>
        <scope>${dependency.scope}</scope>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Можно также использовать `properties-maven-plugin`, и зачитывать настройки из файла `application.properties`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>src/config/application.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

В файле `application.properties` должно быть:

```
dependency.scope=provided
```

---

См. [Maven Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) | [Difference between compile and provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6647178/11141611)

Comment: так же можно использовать профили `<profile>`  и перечислить настройки для каждого контура